# Get actual height of elements composited using :before and :after

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get the actual height in javascript (jquery is fine too) of an element that is drawn using `:before` and `:after`?

Checkout this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a7rhdk86/

Thanks!

Comment: pseudo elements absolutely positionned doesn't affect element flow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `window.getComputedStyle` to access the styles of the :before pseudo-element. See http://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element . However, this gets the css height and width of the element, not the bounding box after the rotation transform.

Getting into hacky territory, I borrowed code from http://upshots.org/javascript/jquery-copy-style-copycss , copied all the styles from the pseudo element to an actual element, added it to the DOM and used [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect) to get the bounding box.

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector(".arrow"), ":before"
    )

var dest = {}
if (style.length) {
     for (var i = 0, l = style.length; i < l; i++) {
         prop = style[i];
         camel = prop.replace(/\-([a-z])/, camelize);
         val = style.getPropertyValue(prop);
         dest[camel] = val;
     }
 } else {
     for (prop in style) {
         camel = prop.replace(/\-([a-z])/, camelize);
         val = style.getPropertyValue(prop) || style[prop];
         dest[camel] = val;
     }
 }

var copy = $("<div />").css(dest)
copy.appendTo(".arrow")
var boundingRect = copy[0].getBoundingClientRect()
console.log(boundingRect.height)
console.log(boundingRect.width)
copy.remove()

function camelize(a, b) {
    return b.toUpperCase();
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/omahlama/mybzymp7/1/

Comment: You are right, it get's the height of the element, not the area that is covered after the transform. Not much use :(

Comment: Awesome, this worked! Can I suggest you edit your answer so it will just contain the correct solution? This would be best for people who stumble upon this question in the future. I'll accept your answer once it is edited.

Comment: Edited the answer for clarity, you were right that it would have been confusing without reading the whole comment thread.