# Get offsetLeft of pseudo elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, pseudo-element

Is there a way to get the offsetLeft of a pseudo element using only javascript ?

I am able to inspect the ::before element through the chrome devtools console and get its offsetLeft.

As window.getComputedStyle(elem, ':before') gives the computed styles for ::before, is there something similar to access the offsetLeft ?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle to attract more attention to your question

Comment: :D it has been years since I had asked this question. I remember faintly that I had manipulated with some property of the parent elem to get the approx offsetLeft of the pseudo elem. 

However my understanding is as the pseudo elems are hidden elements and not really part of DOM, they dont have access to DOM properties..

I may be wrong as it has been a few years since I have worked on this. But would like to know if you have any other way of doing it

Comment: Well, I just clicked on 'unanswered questions' and stumbled upon this. Set up a fiddle and will give a look

Comment: Kind of a weird request, ngl. It's a pretty straightforward question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already figured this out, but I stumbled on this question looking for the answer myself, and I'm pretty confident that the answer is no. Not without some hacky workarounds, at least.

Over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27377952/1093272) someone wanting the fully CSS-transformed height of a pseudo element used `window.getComputedStyle()` to pull all the styles off, slap them on a real element, and then access the bounding rect of that.

But since we're only needing the untransformed position in the viewport, we may not need all that. If it's absolutely positioned within its parent, would be enough to just grab its parent's offsetLeft, then offset that with getComputedStyle to get the real thing:

```
var pseudoStyles = window.getComputedStyle(parent, ":before");
var pseudoOffsetLeft = parent.offsetLeft + parseFloat(pseudoStyles.left) + "px"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4q5uy2af/

It's not as good as getBoundingClientRect since it doesn't take into account CSS transforms, but offsetLeft doesn't do that anyway. And if the pseudo element has `position: fixed`, the offsetLeft can be calculated purely from the styles. If the browser's still in control of placing it in the flow, though, I think things get trickier. You can copy the styles to a real element, but you'll need to hide the pseudo element while you're examining its stand-in's offsetLeft.